# How to distribute templated items from 2 lists on Canvas, based on bind to X and Y position properties, in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I need to paint templated items from 2 Lists on Canvas, according to X and Y position properties. Problem is that the items are not painted in the appropriate coordinates, they are in [0,0] coordinates.

I have a MainWindow.xaml View and corresponding .cs file. I made a new ViewModel, where i have an ObservableCollection of rails. Each rail has its List of Vertices and List of Edges. These Lists are populated with many vertexes and edges. Currently, collection of rails has *only one rail*(will change in future).

In MainWindow.xaml I created 2 DataTemplates, one for vertex and one for edge, and created a Selector which returns the other template based on last returned template. This part works fine.

Here's **MainWindow.xaml** (**MainWindow.xaml.cs** has one basic functioning button event, rest is unchanged(since the time of creation of the file)):

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ViewModels:TratViewModel x:Key="Trat"></ViewModels:TratViewModel>
        <Converters:SwitchListConverter x:Key="BodUsekSwitcher"></Converters:SwitchListConverter>
        <Template:TratItemTemplateSelector x:Key="TratItemSelector"></Template:TratItemTemplateSelector>
</Window.Resources>
```

I also have the DataTemplate-s for vertex and edge in Window.Resources, but since they are correct and this question will be long, I am omitting them.
Rest of MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="150">
                <TabControl DataContext="{StaticResource Trat}" ItemsSource="{Binding ZoznamTrati}">

                    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="My rail"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                <Canvas Width="760" Height="100" Background="DodgerBlue">

                                    <ItemsControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TratItemSelector}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BodUsekSwitcher}">
                                                <Binding Path="BodList" />
                                                <Binding Path="UsekList" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>

                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <Canvas/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                                        <!-- Maybe error here? -->
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding AktualneX}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding AktualneY}"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </Canvas>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>
            </StackPanel>
```

As you can see, I put in TabControl, set the DataContext to my ViewModel(in there is my list of rails, with *only one rail* at the moment) and set ItemsSource to the list of rails.
Tab header shows the name of rail("My rail").
Items of the tab are ScrollViewers with Canvas. Canvas has ItemsControl, which picks either from List of Vertices(*BodList*) or List of Edges(*UsekList*) (picking implemented with switcher, code is below). These lists are in my rail(gptrat, can find in TratViewModel code below). There is also a Template Selector, which selects appropriate template based on type of item(vertex/edge). This selector works fine.

Here's **TratViewModel**:

```
namespace Editor.ViewModels
{
    public class TratViewModel
    {
        private int _y;
        private int _x;
        public int AktualneY
        {
            get
            {
                return _y;
            }

            set
            {
                _y = value;
            }
        }

        public int AktualneX
        {
            get
            {
                return _x;
            }

            set
            {
                _x = value;
            }
        }

        // List of Rails
        private ObservableCollection<GP_Trat> _zoznamTrati;
        public ObservableCollection<GP_Trat> ZoznamTrati
        {
            get
            {
                return _zoznamTrati;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_zoznamTrati != value)
                {
                    _zoznamTrati = value;
                    // NotifyPropertyChanged
                }
            }
        }

        public TratViewModel() {
            // List of Rails
            ZoznamTrati = new ObservableCollection<GP_Trat>();

            // The one rail i read from XML file, works OK
            // It contains List of Vertices and List of Edges, also OK
            GP_Trat gptrat = GPIO.ReadGPTrat("PathToXMLFile");
            ZoznamTrati.Add(gptrat);

            // Setting the coordinates
            AktualneX = 20;
            AktualneY = 50;

        }
```

Here's the converter **BodUsekSwitcher**(in English, VertexEdgeSwitch):

```
namespace Editor.Converters
{
    public class SwitchListConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        static int poslednyTyp = 0;
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Switching between Vertex and Edge Template
            if (poslednyTyp == 0)
            {
                poslednyTyp = 1;
                return values[1];       // EdgeList
            }
            else
            {
                poslednyTyp = 0;
                return values[0];       // VertexList
            }
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the wrong result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MevkJ.jpg .
I set X and Y to 20 and 50, respectively(as you can see in constructor in TratViewModel), so they should be a bit to the right and down.

I am also curious if there is every vertex and edge painted on the Canvas.

If someone knows how to navigate in this mess, please help.

Comment: I doubt that "automatically switching" the ItemsSource collection like this will work at all. Better put two ItemsControls with different source collections and different ItemTemplates on top of each other, one for the lines and one for the points.

Comment: @marting: What is the actual `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` being set to exactly?

Comment: @mm8 It should bind to the list of vertices or list of edges, the converter decides which one. The logic of the "converter" is simple - since I want to have edges below vertices, it first returns list of edges, then list of vertices, and the switching goes until the last vertex, because the number of vertices is equal to number of edges + 1.

Comment: @marting: That doesn't answer my question, does it? Could you please provide a reproducible sample of your issue?